# Error compiling MonoMac on Mac OS 10.9.1

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I am trying to compile MonoMac on Mac OS 10.9.1
The instructions are straightforward, so I execute them:

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/maccore.git
git clone https://github.com/mono/monomac.git
cd monomac
make
```

Unfortunately it fails:

```
[...]
MonoDevelop Build Tool
INFO:Found Xcode, version 5.0.2 (3335.32).
INFO:Xamarin.iOS not installed. Can't find mtouch.
Loading solution: /Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/ButtonMadness.sln
   Loading solution: /Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/ButtonMadness.sln
      Loading projects ..
Building Solution: ButtonMadness (Debug)
   Building: ButtonMadness (Debug)
      Performing main compilation...
      /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/bin/mcs /noconfig "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll" -nostdlib
      "/out:/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/bin/Debug/ButtonMadness.exe" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll"
      "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll"
      "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll"
      "/r:/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll"
      /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /main:SamplesButtonMadness.MainClass /t:exe "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/Main.cs"
      "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/MainMenu.xib.designer.cs"
      "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/DropDownButton.cs" "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/TestWindow.cs"
      "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/TestWindowController.cs" "/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/TestWindow.xib.designer.cs" 
      Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

      /Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/TestWindowController.cs(65,15): error CS1061: Type `MonoMac.AppKit.NSMenu' does not contain a definition for `InsertItematIndex' and no extension
      method `InsertItematIndex' of type `MonoMac.AppKit.NSMenu' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
      /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)


      Build complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings
/Users/nico/src/monomac/samples/ButtonMadness/TestWindowController.cs(65,15) : error CS1061: Type `MonoMac.AppKit.NSMenu' does not contain a definition for `InsertItematIndex' and no extension method `InsertItematIndex' of type `MonoMac.AppKit.NSMenu' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
make[1]: [all] Error 1 (ignored)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C MicroSamples
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../../src/MonoMac.dll', needed by `MonoMac.dll'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this as well. It succeeded fine the first time, but was failing every time after. However, I finally got it to work by doing a

`make clean`

then re-doing a

`make`

and it then worked.